# Register new event/reminder in windows 10 calendar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++-winrt

After hours of trying to find a way to register a new event or reminder via (c++) win32 API into windows calendar, we had no luck!
So how would someone do this via native C++ API?

Comment: The [`Appointments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appointments) namespace may be the place to look into. Probably, though, what you're really trying to do here involves interacting with the calendar provider. The Calendar App in Windows is just an aggregator and UI for (cloud-based) calendar providers.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes I already took a look at it, but I just need a working example from the C++ API :(

Comment: There is no C++ API in Windows, so it's not immediately clear what the problem is.

Comment: @IInspectable Actually, the appointments you mentioned are available through C++/WinRT, we just need a working sample of registering appointments in the user calendar